# mobile app development SDK

Tags: c#, java, eclipse, mobile, sdk

I am looking to build a native app for both apple and android I have a web system built in c# mvc4 so this is my primary language. I have been looking for the quickest way to develop both but dont know where to start. Any recommendations regarding any SDK's. I need to incorporate push alerts to the device and download server content.

I dont have access to a Mac, ideally I have been looking for a one stop SDK. I have seen phone gap and umbrella sdk. Phone gap requires apple mac and umbrella SDK has limited features in its API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android you will either program in C++ or Java, and for iOS you will need to program in ObjectiveC, a language specific to Apple.

Primary development IDEs: Eclipse for Android -> XCODE for iOS

[Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

[Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/)

Comment: I font have access to a Mac, deally I have been looking for a one stop SDK. I have seen phone gap and umbrella sdk. Phone gap requires apple mac and umbrella SDK has limited features in its API

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to meet your key goal of a native app with an all-in-one solution. Apple's iOS requires native development in Objective-C with compilation and testing through XCode. You'll also need an Apple Developers license ($99/year) for even testing your app. That's just a simple requirement of any iOS app development process.

The better question, do you really need native code? If you go for a wrapped, web-app approach, you can have notifications on all of your major platforms via the Cordova/PhoneGap environment. You can setup a [one-stop development environment via PhoneGap templates](http://devgirl.org/2012/10/04/cross-platform-phonegap-aka-cordova-project-templates-in-a-jiffy/). Yes, you'll still need a Mac for testing and deployment (iOS) and Eclipse for Android testing and deployment, but you'll get the one-stop development environment you want.